# Received Event from customer with Fault Offset. Using map file and cod files to find the exact location of crash

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-c++-2010

Having recently released a product, I encourage customers, if they experience a crash, to send me the corresponding entry from the Event Viewer.

This provides me an error type and a fault offset.

I keep a folder for every build with a map file and all the cod files. I throw a pdb file in there as well, but I don't distribute it.

A. I take the offset and subtract the closest map file entry to get a function offset.

B. I go into the cod file for that class (one source file per class), find the start of that function.

C. I add this to the function offset I calculated from the map file. This gives me a relative address within the source file.

D. This relative address should give me a line number where the crash occurred.

E. With a tiny bit of knowledge about how C++ instructions are broken down into assembler, I can pinpoint exactly what part of the instruction failed.

Here's my question: In part A above, I subtract another 0x00001000 from the Fault Offset. This seems to always work. Why?

Hopefully relevant information from the map file:

```
Preferred load address is 00400000

Start         Length     Name                   Class
0001:00000000 002f19e4H .text                   CODE
0001:002f19f0 000179a7H .text$x                 CODE
...
Address         Publics by Value              Rva+Base       Lib:Object
0000:00000000       __except_list              00000000     <absolute>
0000:00000373       ___safe_se_handler_count   00000373     <absolute>
0000:00000000       ___ImageBase               00400000     <linker-defined>
0001:00000000       ??3CObject@@SGXPAX@Z       00401000 f i A-------.obj
0001:00000010       ?CreateStockObject@CGdiObject@@QAEHH@Z 00401010 f i A-------.obj
```

So, I can see why 0x00401000 should be added, and this is consistent with what I see when I examine the code in the disassembly.

But why is the Fault Offset off by 0x00001000? Is that something I can absolutely count on every time? Because I'm looking at a customer report that doesn't make a lot of sense - the code wouldn't fault at the line indicated unless there was a timing-related stack issue (which would be fairly horrible to debug if it can't be recreated).

Comment: You may find it easier to work with a crash dump file.  You can load the file into Visual Studio and have it recreate the context of the crash.

Comment: Thanks for replying. It's a lot to expect a customer even to check the Event Viewer. While I'd love the luxury of having a stack trace to review, getting anything more isn't a realistic expectation. Customers are (justifiably) annoyed enough by the crash itself, and maybe one in ten is even willing to report it, let alone respond to instructions on how to open the Event Viewer. As long as I keep an archive for every build, I can get something out of the event as long as I can count on subtracting 0x00001000 working every time. The tough ones are all buffer overruns anyway.